# Jmeter Runtime data validation and writing to a csv

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am having a search API which will return bunch  records(first name, last name, etc). If the DB have the records it will return the attributes with values else  it will return  as Null. I want to print or write the records  for which value is available, Null blocks can be discarded. Could you please guide how to check and capture the same

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where and in what form you want the output the approaches will differ therefore try to be more specific next time, for the time being here is a "generic" solution

1. Extract data from the response into a [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using suitable [JMeter Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors). Basically the same process which is used in [dynamic data correlation in JMeter tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter). Give the variables meaningful names like `firstName`, `lastName`, etc.
2. Define [`sample_variables` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) in *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter "bin" folder) as somma-separated values like:

   ```
   sample_variables=firstName,lastName,etc.
   ```
3. Next time you run your JMeter test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) the resulting .jtl file will contain the respective values for all defined Sample Variables

Comment: Thanks for the comments. What i was looking is to capture the all the FirstName and Last Name data  which is not coming as  null from the  Jason response.